# How do I cause Google Input Tools to reload a custom canonical transliteration scheme?

Tags: windows-7, language, ime

I use Google Input Tools on Windows 7 with my own [custom canonical transliteration scheme](http://www.google.com/inputtools/windows/canonical.html) for [Malayalam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malayalam). However, to debug this scheme, I have to edit it and cause Google Input Tools to somehow reload the scheme. I cannot find a way to do this without restarting the computer, as silly as it may seem! I think I am missing something obvious on the UI.

How do I cause Google Input Tools to reload a custom transliteration scheme from the `/schemes` directory of a language please? If that is not possible, how can I quit Google Input Tools and restart it (at which point the schemes will presumably be reloaded)?

Comment: Have you tried just logging out and logging back in instead of rebooting?  How about killing the Google Input Tools process via Task manager and restarting it?  How about killing Explorer and restarting it?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Restarting GoogleInputService doesn't seem to work. Didn't try the other two options (will do soon), but they strike me as just as disruptive to my iteration as restarting. I am looking for a "proper" way to do this since I have quite a few edits to try.

Comment: @TECHIE007 Logging off works, but restarting explorer doesn't. However, it appears that Google Input Tools has a registered service (GoogleInputService) as well as an application (GoogleInputHandler.exe). Stopping the application from the task manager works - it restarts automatically, it looks like. Hence the solution is to just stop GoogleInputHandler.exe from the task manager. Thanks again!